# MySQL: update with join using GROUP_CONCAT: ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql

so I am updating a table that's functionally equivalent to:

```
create table NODE(
   group_name varchar(100) not null,
   full_name varchar(100) not null,
   dependency longtext,
   is_top ENUM('0','1') not null default 0,
   ...
);
```

The dependency is a concatenation of the `full_name` of all the other nodes that get triggered when something happens to this node that needs to trickle down to the ancestor nodes. There is a top level node for which all are 'children' of. Occasionally a bunch more get added to the group and I need to update the `dependency` of the top level node with `full_names` of the other child nodes as one giant string separated by '&'.

Here was my query:

```
update NODE n1 
join NODE n2 
on n2.group_name=n1.group_name 
set n1.dependency=GROUP_CONCAT(n2.full_name SEPARATOR '&') 
where n1.is_top='1' and n2.is_top='0' and n1.group_name='MY GROUP NAME';
```

error:

```
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
```

My understanding is this should be fine, after all you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` in a select statement, and I do it all the time, I don't understand how this is invalid.

for the curious: I did not design this database, and yes I re-named things to hide the true nature of the database and how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
update NODE n1 
join 
(
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(full_name SEPARATOR '&') as name_concat, 
        group_name
    FROM NODE
    WHERE
       is_top='0'
    GROUP BY group_name
) n2 
ON n2.group_name=n1.group_name 
SET n1.dependency=n2.name_concat
WHERE 
    n1.is_top='1' and 
    n1.group_name='MY GROUP NAME';
```

You shouldn't use `GROUP_CONCAT` without `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks! I had to make a small edit to take out the n2.full_name in GROUP_CONCAT and replaced with just full name but that was perfect! I wonder why it has to be done this way.

Comment: @jasondancks, oups! that one slipped. i've updated my answer anyway. Glad I could help!